# Passing custom args in paginate_links

Tags: pagination

For example i've `domain.com/about?project=1` but i've permalinks enabled and i'm using thins to generate the pagination [paginate_links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links#Examples). The proble is that the links generated are like this `domain.com/about?project=1/page/1` and it breaks everything because the project is taken as `1/page/1`

There is a way to get `domain.com/about/project/1/page/1` in the paginations links? I'm submitting that from a form using get to display the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add arguments to the links in paginate posts, use the `'add_args'` argument in the function. You have to pass the arguments as an associative array. So, to add `project=1` to the end of all your links, you would do this:

```
global $wp_query;
paginate_links(array(
  'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
  'current' => (get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
  'base' => 'http://domain.com/about/%_%',
  'format' => 'page/%#%',
  'add_args' => array( 'project' => 1 /* or whatever the project number is*/ ),
));
```

Hope that helped!

### EDIT

To get `domain.com/about/projects/1/page/1`, you can add a custom permastruct. I'm going to assume `about` is a page.

```
function wpse21802_init(){
  add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]+)/projects/([^/])/?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&project=$matches[2]', 'top' );
  add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]+)/projects/([^/])/page/(/d+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&project=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse21802_init' );
```

After adding that code, flush the rewrite rules by going to Settings -> Permalinks.

Comment: But that generates http://domain.com/about/page/1?project=1

Comment: "I'm submitting that from a form using get to display the project." Project is a `$_GET` variable in that link, no? `'add_args' => array( 'project' => absint($_GET['project'])`

Comment: Yes, but again read the main question:
There is a way to get domain.com/about/project/1/page/1 in the paginations links? I'm submitting that from a form using get to display the project.

Comment: I updated my answer, but I'd also like to point out that WordPress already supports that url structure just from using page hierarchy.

Comment: Or `'add_args' => array( '#mydiv')` if you want the link click to scroll to a div for example.