# WP_Query pagination using only numbers instead of /page/1 on URL

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination

I don't get whats happening here.

I'm on a child-page template, generating a WP_Query for Custom Post Types on the fly, like this:

```
$notrel = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'posts_per_page' => $perpage,
    'monthnum' => $mes,
    'year' => $ano,
    'paged' => $paged
));
```

Loops and $_GET filters for `post_type`, `monthnum` and `year`are all working perfectly. But pagination is giving me trouble.

A) If i try the URL `http://example.com/parent-page/child-page/page/4/` i get `paged = 1`.

B) On the other hand, `http://example.com/parent-page/child-page/4/` correctly gives `paged = 4` but pagination doesn't work since `next_posts_link` automatically shapes URLs like A.

I guess `/page/4/` is standard, so why is it not working here? Is it maybe the rewrite parameter on register_post_type?

**EDIT:** still not solved, se this -> [paginate_links() adds empty href to first page and previous link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/52405/7890)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really solve it, but got around with the help of [Passing custom args in paginate_links](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/21802/7890) and [Custom paging function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45829/7890).

Initially I even thought of writing a patch to `next_posts_link`, but as it turns out, the URL formatting problem lies way below in the function soup, and that is really a downer when all I wanted was to reuse some earlier code that went into this template when it was still static.

My solution for now was to leave it all behind and start fresh with `paginate_links()`. Turns out that paginate_links doesn't care about permalink structure and always appends `?page=4` to the URL which just makes a lot more sense. :)

UPDATE: 
Followinfg along, I got this problem -> [paginate_links() adds empty href to first page and previous link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/52405/7890) which was properly solved after all. :)